# mybatis configuration file error

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I get the following error when running the configuration xml file from command line as stated on mybatis site.  I run “java –jar mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2.jar –configfile mbg.xml –overwrite –verbose”

error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have copy-pasted the command from their website. The problem is they used a strange character for "-".

As a proof, go to [this](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directasciiidentifier.html) website and insert the "-" (dash) character from their website command and click on "Show ASCII Key Code". It will show an window where the decimal key for that character is 8211. If you insert from your keyboard the "-" character, the decimal key displayed is 45, which is the correct character.

So, you need to type the command by hand or you can copy-paste the command below:

```
java -jar mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2.jar -configfile mbg.xml -overwrite -verbose
```